# Scrape https://socialblade.com/

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I am new to Scrapy and trying to scrape https://socialblade.com/ website to get the channel id of the most viewed and most subscribed Youtuber of a country.

The way I am doing it is to click on the link to a Youtuber on the main listing page (e.g. https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/country/pk/mostsubscribed). Then it opens a new page, and the last part of the new opened page contains the channel id (e.g. https://socialblade.com/youtube/channel/UC4JCksJF76g_MdzPVBJoC3Q).

Here is my code:

```
import scrapy

class SocialBladeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "socialblade"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/country/pk/mostviewed',
            'https://socialblade.com/youtube/top/country/pk/mostsubscribed'
        ]

        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_url(self, response):
        data = {
            'url': response.url.split('/')[-1],
            'displayName': response.css('div#YouTubeUserTopInfoBlockTop div h1::text').extract_first()
        }

        yield {
            response.meta['country']: {
                response.meta['key']: data
            }
        }

    def parse(self, response):
        key = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        country = response.url.split("/")[-2]

        for a in response.css('a[href^="/youtube/user/"]'):
            request = scrapy.Request(url='https://socialblade.com' + a.css('::attr(href)').extract_first(), callback=self.parse_url)
            request.meta['key'] = key
            request.meta['country'] = country
            yield request
```

**Issue is:** after scraping these two urls I should get total 500 records. But I am only getting 348 records. I did the R&D but unable to find solution.

Does anyone have any advice on how to solve this?

Comment: Could it just be that whatever you do with the data yielded by start_requests is combining the records, finding that there are 152 channels that are in both lists?

Comment: @Sumurai8 thanks for reply. most probably that is the case. so i have to scrap both url individually to get all 500 records? but i have large list of urls to scrap for every country. can you guide me how i can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `dont_filter=True` to your requests if you do not want to filter out duplicate requests.

For more information, see the [documentation about Request](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request).